# Tomcat error - Status code 404, resource not available

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I am creating basic REST application. I am getting requested resource not available when trying to run on Tomcat server. I am using Java configuration (no xml) in the project. I have tried all possible solutions available on Stackoverflow, none of them worked for me. I have been trying for almost 2 hours. I need help to solve this error.

[HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource (/spring-rest-demo/test/hello) is not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku8ZL.png)

DemoRestController

```
//imports

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class DemoRestController {

    // add code for the "/hello" endpoint
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
    
}
```

MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer

```
//imports

public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { DemoAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

DemoAppConfig

```
//imports

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.springdemo")
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

}
```

Comment: Have you checked tomcat logs?

Comment: @Ivan I do not see anything in the log, this is the log--INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [44] ms
Oct 17, 2020 9:50:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Oct 17, 2020 9:50:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [1853] milliseconds

Comment: How do you deploy your app on tomcat? And how do you run tomcat?

Comment: @Ivan I downloaded tomcat on my machine, then I add Tomcat server in Eclipse. Next I right click on project and Run on Tomcat server. And this is Maven project

Comment: From tomcat logs it looks like your application is not deployed to tomcat at all. You may need to Google how to run application on tomcat from eclipse. You may need to add a step to build war file before starting tomcat from eclipse

Comment: @Ivan I did that, I followed the steps in this doc- https://www.zoftino.com/running-maven-web-application-on-tomcat-in-eclipse#:~:text=Build%20Web%20Application,-To%20compile%2C%20test&text=In%20the%20run%20configurations%20window,to%20create%20a%20war%20file.                 Still same error. What can I do?

Comment: Can you attach full tomcat logs? `tail` all your logs, hit the url - then share the logs here. It can help to take a look at. Are you getting access log when you are trying to hit?